# Stacking multiple solutions into a single 3D plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```
y1=tanh(3*x+5*t);
y2=5*cos(x+3*t);
y3=exp(-x)*sin(2*x+t);
```

How can I plot `y1`, `y2` and `y3` into a single 3D plot for the fixed value of `t=0.5`?

Comment: [`hold on`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) ?

Comment: But a fixed value of `t` will just give you 1 point, so 3 points in total. Not sure if that is worth plotting....

Comment: @Biguri, if we don't fix the value of t, then how can we them into single 3D plot, can you provide me the code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `yn` and `x` are arrays of values and have been evaluated with t=0.5, the [following code](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/graphics-ex99259345-plot-multiple-lines) will plot all 3 functions on one figure:

```
figure
plot(x,y1,x,y2,x,y3)
```

I'm guessing you are additionally asking how to evaluate `yn` for a range of `x`. Simply define `yn` as an array and loop over all values of `x`:

```
y1 = [];
x = [1 5 8 17];
t=0.5;
for xi = x
    y1 = [y1 ; tanh(3*xi+5*t)];
end
```